# How is JSON Web Token Based authentication stateless?

Tags: jwt

In the API, jwt.sign will create a key and sends along with the response let's say while login. So, when the client make another request, the API/Server uses jwt.verify to check the user logged in is authentic. Here to verify the key, the server has to store the same right? So how can it be stateless?

I am pretty confused and could be wrong in this case, but please do advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jwt.sign` creates a signed token in which the signature is a hash calculated with the token content and a secret key. The secret key is fix. The signed token is sent to the client who requested it. When the client sends a request containing the token in the authorization header, the token will be veryfied by again calculating the hash. There's no need to store the token or signature anywhere.